# django ForeignKey model filter in admin-area?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms, django-admin-filters

Hi I need really **very very simple example.** First my models:

```
#This my student models
from django.db import models
SEX_CHOICES= (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
)
class Students(models.Model):
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    student_sex = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=SEX_CHOICES)
    student_city = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    student_bio = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.student_name
```

O.K. Let see my ClassRooms Model.

```
#This my ClassRooms models
from django.db import models
from myproject.students.models import *
class ClassRooms(models.Model):
    class_number= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    class_student_cities = models.ForeignKey(Students)
    class_year = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.class_number
```

How can i show in the class_student_cities area the Students.student_city datas? I guess that about django-admin area. When i do it withclass_student_cities = models.ForeignKey(Students) i just see in that area the Students.student_name data (ex: John Smith). I want to see JUST Students.student_cities data (ex: NewYork). **Can you give me a little example?**

Should i use something like that:

```
class_student_cities = models.ForeignKey(Students.student_cities)
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe the relationship between Students and ClassRooms?  What do you want to know about cities and classrooms?  (E.g. "What are all the cities of students in a classroom?") From the model names, I would expect Student to have a field like `classroom = models.ForeignKey(ClassRoom)`, not the other way around.  Take a look at the documentation and examples for [foreign keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) in django.

Comment: FYI I merged your unregistered account into this one.

Answer (score 1):

Try redifinition **unicode** method.

```
def __unicode__(self):
        return self.student_city
```

So you'll see in the field student city.

Well, I tried to remake your application to set data with forms class. Something like this in admin.py in your application:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from myapp.models import *

class ClassRoomsAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ClassRoom
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        super(ClassRoomsAdminForm, self).__init__(*arg, **kwargs)
        self.fields[' class_student_cities'].choices = [(csc.id,csc.student_city) for csc in Students.objects.all()

class ClassRoomsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ClassRoomsAdminForm

admin.site.register(ClassRooms,ClassRoomsAdmin)
```

Maybe you'll need to fix something, but I hope it will work. You will set **init** function to your forms, so in admin panel you set all choices to everything you keep in your Students model. csc.id you'll need to make this object iterable (cities aren't unique) and then you can choose everything from Students model to set in the field.

Comment: I'm sorry for so many editions, but I want perfect code as answer this question.

Comment: hmm in your second example I get syntax error in this line:

self.fields[' class_student_cities'].choices = [(csc.id,csc.student_city) for csc in Students.objects.all()

Comment: Ok I fix it lets try it again :)

Comment: AttributeError at /admin/classes/classrooms/add/
'ClassRoomsForm' object has no attribute 'fields'

Comment: Ah, sorry, when I edit my entry, I delete important thing. Look now at the example, I add 'super' line, to get access to object.

Comment: You are my hero! Many Thanks! Jus a little fix:


super(ClassRoomsAdminForm, self).__init__(*arg, **kwargs)

Comment: Fixed in answer. I'm glad that finally my django knowledge help someone and I would be pleased, if you could mark answer as accepted. :)